# How to check if the value of key is ARRAY or STRUCT in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract values from JSON object but I don't know if the value is Array or an Object as i want to write a generic code that will check array or object and return value accordingly.

I have two JSON as below

JSON one:

```
"fruit":[{"apples":5,"oranges":10},{"apples":2,"oranges":4}]
```

JSON two:

```
"fruit":{"apples":5,"oranges":10}
```

I have to get value of `oranges` but the value of `fruit` may change.
How to check type of value and extract value in BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 id, '{"fruit":[{"apples":5,"oranges":10},{"apples":2,"oranges":4}]}' json union all 
  select 2, '{"fruit":{"apples":5,"oranges":10}}'
)
select id,
  json_extract(x, '$.apples') apples,
  json_extract(x, '$.oranges') oranges
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(ifnull(json_extract_array(json, '$.fruit'), [json_extract(json, '$.fruit')])) x
```

with output

[image]